# Angular4 unclear exception After building the application

Tags: angular, build, aot

My application works fine using `ng serve`, but after building it using `ng build --prod` I get this exception:

```
vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: No provider for e!
    at E (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at x (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at t._throwOrNull (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at t._getByKeyDefault (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at t._getByKey (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at t.get (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at Ue (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at t.get (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at Sn (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
    at En (vendor.350ea18ab78ed7d28861.bundle.js:1)
```

The problem is that I can't locate the source of this exception, I don't know where it's coming from !
I'm using Angular version 4 and ng CLI version 1.4.2 and this is my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.88",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

What should I do ?

Comment: can your try ng serve --aot and check if the issue appears?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo sorry same problem but this time I get this: No provider for NgForm !!

Comment: Then you need to import FormsModule into the modules where you declare components that use ngForm

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I did it's already in the app.module.ts file

Comment: If you have any other modules that declare components which use ngForm, you need to import it to those as well

Comment: the project is working fine when using `ng serve` which means all modules are working good !

Comment: AOT do more strict checks, thats why it complains. You are most likely missing something. Please add the full error log that you get when you execute serve with aot

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I have updated my dependencies to 4.4.3 and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was version issue
After updating to 4.4.3 now everything works fine.
This is my package.json now:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.88",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```